# orders not tracked in GA

Tags: google-analytics

I have followed the below link and added the code in `success.phtml` but my orders are not tracked in Google Analytics. In Chrome, the below error comes

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce

**success.phtml**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    ga('create', '<?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig('google/analytics/account') ?>');
    ga('require', 'ec');
    <?php
        foreach ($items as &$item) {
            echo $block->getItemJs($trans['id'], $item);
        }
        echo $block->getTransactionJs($trans);

    ?>
    ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

> Uncaught ReferenceError: ga is not defined

Can anyone help me,?

Answer (score 2):

**I think you will need to call analytics.js also**

As per description [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/) it should be like below

```
<!-- Google Analytics -->
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
<!-- End Google Analytics -->
```

Answer (score 1):

> analytics.js file is misssing on your page. It should be like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function()
      {  
        (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
         m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
        })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

        ga('create', '<?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig('google/analytics/account') ?>');
        ga('require', 'ec');
        <?php
            foreach ($items as &$item) {
                echo $block->getItemJs($trans['id'], $item);
            }
            echo $block->getTransactionJs($trans);

        ?>
        ga('send', 'pageview');
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you recently upgrade your Magento version? Magento added (I believe in **1.9.1**) a configuration setting in the admin that lets you select different Google Analytics code types to use throughout your site.

After this upgrade, the code setting on my site switched from a "Universal Analytics" code to a "Google Analytics" code and gave me the same error:
`Uncaught ReferenceError: ga is not defined`

Try switching it back to Universal Analytics. Go To:

> Admin > Configuration > Sales > Google API > Google Analytics > Type

Set it to **Universal Analytics**

You can see the conditional for the two different GA code types and what the code looks like in:

> app\design\frontend\base\default\template\googleanalytics\ga.phtml